# Am I properly identifying the resistor terminal voltage?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits

> The frequency applied to a circuit of voltage 120 V with a **real** coil and a resistor has a value of 50 Hz. The resistance of the resistor is 10 $\Omega$. The voltage at the resistor terminals $u_1=60V$. The voltage at the coil's terminals is $u_2=90V$.

$$\nu=50\text{ Hz}$$
$$R=10\ {\Omega }$$ 
$$U=120\text{ V}$$
$$u_1=60\text{ V   - resistor terminal voltage}$$
$$u_2=90\text{ V   - coil terminal voltage}$$

> Find:
>
> - the intensity of the current $I$.
> - the parameters of the coil.

I think by "parameters of the coil", it is meant the resistance and the impedance of the coil.

$$I=?$$
$$L=?$$
$$R_L=?$$

I've been trying a bit, but I am quite poor at physics. This problem is suggested in a book, I want to prepare for a testpaper.

What I've been thinking of is to calculate $$\cos\phi=\frac{U_r }{U}=\frac{60}{120}=\frac{1}{2}$$ $$\implies \phi=\pi/3$$  But I am not sure if the resistor terminal voltage is the same thing with $U_r$. Is this right?

Comment: Hi Bujanca, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! This site is for conceptual questions about physics, not general homework help - which means the first part of your question is fine here, but the second part may not be. I edited your question a bit to fix it up. Still, though, I'm not sure if you've provided enough information to get a proper answer. Could you quote the complete problem statement in your question?

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky thanks a lot for help. I hope that now it does fit the site requirements :)

Comment: Yep, that should definitely help! I edited it again only to "spruce up" the formatting: it's kind of conventional to quote the problem statement using blockquote syntax, `>`. Hopefully I got it right ;-)

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky yes, you did. Thank you for help and time, i appreciate

Answer (score 1):

Ok , it was a nice one.!
Let's consider the real inductor as a pure inductor plus resistance pair.
[image]

the value of I(rms) can be get using the Pure resistor outside this pair,

> U=I(rms)*R2    ;  r2=10;
>
> I(rms)=6;

Now potential drop across real inductor Ulr (90) , across pure inductor Ul and across resistance Ur are pythagorean triplets.

> Ulr^2=Ul^2+Ur^2;

We get

> 225=R^2+(50L)^2   ; I=6A;

Now , see circuit as a whole;

> potential drop  is ==> sqrt[(10+R)^2  + (50L)^2 ] *6 ; ie. Z*I=120
>
> we get => 100 + R^2 + 2R + (50L)^2 = 400;
>
> use the two equations to get R and L